# Unity Editor Log file path doesn't remain static on SpecialFolders depending on different platforms (Mac/Linux)

Tags: unity-game-engine, logging, path, unity-editor

Well I have been researching the Editor Log file path and I found this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

That says the following:

> Operating System: macOS | Path: ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
>
> Operating System: Windows | Path: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log

The Linux path is: `~/.config/unity3d/Editor.log`

Searching for the equivalent on the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum.

This are the equivalent on diferent platforms:

Linux: https://ibboard.co.uk/Programming/mono-special-folders.html

[image: ...]

Mac: https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/special-folder-values-on-windows-versus-mac/

[image: ...]

They are the same. But in Windows this changes:

[image: ...]

And as you can see this is located at:

[image: ...]

It's equivalent in C# is:

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Unity", "Editor", "Editor.log"));
```

[image: ...]

Is this different or I'm missing something?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? On Windows Unity uses the `LocalApplicationData` directory as a base path for the log file, not the roaming path you listed above. If you need a particular path pass it as a command line parameter to Unity when you start it. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: I asked this because I need to do a cross-platform application and Idk if I'm doing wrong or I have take care of the platform where the Assembly is being executed?

Comment: A cross platform application to do what? Read the Unity log? You'll need to handle the platforms differently but the location of the log file is well documented on each.